# How to apply two modifications on ggplot's colour scale bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I would like to display a scale_color_gradient scale bar that (i) only has a set number of decimal points and (ii) also always displays "0" not "0.00". What is the best way to do this?

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), y = runif(10, 3, 5),z = rnorm(10, 30, .2))
scaled.dat <- data.frame(scale(dat))

ggplot(scaled.dat, aes(x, y, colour = z)) + geom_point()+ 
# Modify the number of decimal points 
  scale_color_gradient(labels = function(x) sprintf("%.5f", x))
# Make zero value display "0" only
  #scale_color_gradient(labels = ~sub("0.0", "0", sprintf("%.1f", .x)))
```

Comment: You can just combine the transformations into one function `scale_color_gradient(labels = function(x) sub("0.00000", "0", sprintf("%.5f", x)))`

Answer (score 0):

Using an `ifelse` you could do:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)

dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 30, .2), y = runif(10, 3, 5), z = rnorm(10, 30, .2))
scaled.dat <- data.frame(scale(dat))

ggplot(scaled.dat, aes(x, y, colour = z)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradient(
    labels = ~ ifelse(.x != 0, sprintf("%.5f", .x), sprintf("%.0f", .x))
  )
```

[image]